# Envio de data abreviada não funciona abreviada asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, textbox, http-post

Estou Criando um formulário no ASP.NET MVC e, criando o campo "DataMensagem", a principio coloquei a TextBox para carregar uma data com o mês por extenso, conforme abaixo:

[image: Imagem do formulário com o campo "Data da mensagem" contendo o mês por extenso.]

***Imagem do formulário com o campo "Data da mensagem" contendo o mês por extenso.***

Abaixo, o código da View do campo "Data da Mensagem":

[image: Imagem do código utilizado para criar o campo "Data da Mensagem" com o mês por extenso]
***Imagem do código da View utilizado para criar o campo "Data da Mensagem" com o mês por extenso.***

Quando crio o campo dessa forma, além de carregar corretamente, eu consigo enviar sem problemas para o banco de dados os dados em caso de uma possível alteração.

Entretanto, quando utilizo o formato para abreviar o Mês e mostrar apenas o número do mesmo, a validação não me permite enviar o mesmo para o banco de dados no caso de uma possível alteração de mensagem.

Abaixo, o formulário com o campo "Data da mensagem" carregado corretamente com o mês abreviado:

[image: Imagem do formulário com o campo "Data da mensagem" contendo o mês abreviado, com o erro apresentado ao clicar no botão "Salvar".]

***Imagem do formulário com o campo "Data da mensagem" contendo o mês abreviado, com o erro apresentado ao clicar no botão "Salvar".***

Abaixo, o código da View do campo "Data da Mensagem" com o mês abreviado:[image: Imagem do código da View utilizado para criar o campo "Data da Mensagem" com o mês abreviado.]
***Imagem do código da View utilizado para criar o campo "Data da Mensagem" com o mês abreviado.***

E abaixo, o model utilizado para o campo "Data da Mensagem":

[image: Model do campo "Data da Mensagem".]

***Model do campo "Data da Mensagem".***

Alguém sabe o porque desse problema está acontecendo e como posso resolvê-lo? Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Poste o código fonte por texto e não por imagem. Fica mais fácil para entender e ajudar.

Comment: Experimenta utilizar DataAnnotations pra definir o formato dele.
`[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MMMM/yyyy}")]`

Comment: Já tentei utilizar o DataAnnotations, e não funcionou. Quando utilizo ele, aparecem a data e horas completos ("26/06/2017 12:00:00" por exemplo), e quando tento enviar os dados, retorna o erro "The field Data da mensagem must be a date."

Comment: Qual Data Annotations você utilizou?

Comment: você quer deixar das 2 formas ou apenas 26/06/2017 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu problema está relacionado com o navegador que está entendendo que o primeiro campo da data é o mês, você pode testar qualquer valor a cima de 12 que vai gerar o mesmo problema pois ele tenta fazer um parse para mês e entende que o valor é inválido.

Você pode perceber que, se colocar 01/02/2017, o asp.net vai receber corretamente o dia 01 e o mês 02, confirmando que o problema de validação é apenas client-side.

Encontrei um snippet ([aqui](https://forums.asp.net/t/2095808.aspx?%20The%20field%20Date%20must%20be%20a%20date%20when%20using%20jQuery%20date%20picker%20inside%20my%20asp%20net%20mvc%204%20web%20application)) à um tempo atrás quando tive esse problema que pode te ajudar (assumindo que você está usando a validação JQuery que vem no MVC por padrão) e eu acabei de criar um console application para testar e resolveu:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>

    $(function () {
        $.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
            if ($.browser.webkit) {

                //ES - Chrome does not use the locale when new Date objects instantiated:
                var d = new Date();

                return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(d.toLocaleDateString(value)));
            }
            else {

                return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value));
            }
        };
    });
</script>
```